# Should I use "_activity = this;"?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Should I use "`_activity = this;`"?

I've seen _activity referenced many times in sample code. So, I arbitrarily decided that it looked like a good practice and have been using in all my code for awhile (over a year). But, before I start spreading the word around more I wanted to find some proper documentation that using a global (activity-local) context variable is good practice or not.

Anybody have ideas/thoughts/links? Know of any pros and cons?

One resource that I have found so far seems to say there are good and bad times to use [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

I know that I *could* use `this` or `MainActivity.this`, but that's not the question.

..Just in case you don't know what I'm talking about, here is a trvial example made up on the spot:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MainActivity _activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _activity = this; // TODO: Find out if this is good practice?
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickButton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(_activity, "Five boxing wizards", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(_activity, "asdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: Another side-question for the comments: By a show of hands, who actually uses `_activity`?

Comment: Why would you need a reference to an object within the object itself? Are you thinking about a `static` reference to it?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have made the case trivial. I'll edit it so that the button is in its own object. I would use the reference throughout large files, possibly with subclasses.

Comment: In those cases, just use `MainActivity.this`. No need to keep an extra reference when you have one which is just as accessible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not good practice.  Simply use `this` in most cases, and `MainActivity.this` when creating an anonymous subclass, etc.

I think the right question to ask yourself is, "does adding this member variable do anything for me", or "is there anything I can do with `_activity` that I can't do with `this`.  I can tell you the answer is "no", but you should decide for yourself whether it is true.

Answer (score 3):

It is not good practice.

Apart from not achieving anything (that can't be done by using `this` directly):

- it makes the parent object bigger (by one reference),
- it is potentially a bit slower, and
- it makes your code more fragile; e.g. if someone accidentally assigns a different value to the variable.

I would argue that the code is *less* readable, but you might not agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not good. If I'm reading code I know what "this" means but if I see that I need to investigate.

Comment: At first, I didn't know what `_activity` was either. But, after seeing it so many times, including in Google's sample code, I now know what it means when I see it.

Comment: Where in Google's sample code? Even the naming convention is not correct it should be mActivity (http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Answer (score 0):

That only makes sense when your outer class is not an activity, but you need one. For example, if you wanted too define your onclicklistener in its own file, you would need to pass in and store a reference (and be careful not too leak as note ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating an unnecessary reference (because the instance is also available via the `this` keyword or `MainActivity.this`, field names prefixed with underscores are discouraged as per the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language: 9. Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)